# Marketing Cloud: Removing multiple rows from a data extension via SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, automationstudio

In Marketing Cloud, we would like to remove multiple rows based on the EmailAddress column, which is the primary key in our permission data extension.  Now, we tried using the code snippet for Server-Side JavaScript (SSJS) from the SF official developer's site, but that only removes a single contact at a time. I don't know how to add additional email addresses for removal in the SSJS code snippet below. Please help.

```
    <script runat=server>

Platform.Load("core", "1");

        var permissionDE= DataExtension.Init("Preference_Management");

        permissionDE.Rows.Remove(["EmailAddress"], ["customer@customer-emailDomain.com"]);


    </script>
```

Comment: It's very useful but still does not show how to add multiple records for deletion. It only suggests that you can do that.

Comment: Actually it does, Gregory explains how to use DeleteData function to delete rows from a DE. The main purpose of answers here is to help YOU find the solution and not write code on your behalf.

Comment: Actually, people on this site have been helpful in providing more insight to me on similar topics, even if that meant adding just one line of code just to show how it should look like in the end. And I'm very grateful to them and always sang their praises. Apparently, not everyone is like that. Nevermind.

Comment: I believe I myself answered some of your questions here. Anyways, not here to argue about this. Goodluck!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend utilizing WSProxy instead. It is likely to be faster and you can do bulk 'deletes' in a single call, instead of requiring multiple calls.

In my example, I am assuming RemovalDE is a DE you created that contains all the email addresses you need removed from Preference_Management.

```js
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core","1");
var deCustKey = "RemovalDE";
var de = DataExtension.Init(deCustKey);
var data = de.Rows.Retrieve();
var objs = [];
for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
  deCustKey = "Preference_Management";
  var email = data[i].EmailAddress
  objs.push({
    CustomerKey: deCustKey,
    Keys: [{Name:"EmailAddress", Value:email}]
  });
}
var prox = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
var res = prox.deleteBatch("DataExtensionObject", objs);
</script>
```

This will then remove all the emailaddresses from 'Preference_Management' that were in 'RemovalDE' within a single API call. To verify results, you can Write() your `res` variable (like so: `Write("<br><br>" + Stringify(res));`) and run it on a cloudpage where it will output.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** For those having the same need, here's how I got multiple records to be deleted via SSJS. Since there were 152 records, I had to prepare & format the data offline (in Excel) for proper insertion into the SSJS code in Automation Studio.  Of course, if anyone has more elegant code to achieve this, please comment on this topic.

**SSJS:**

```
<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("core", "1");

var permissionDE= DataExtension.Init("Preference_Management");

permissionDE.Rows.Remove(["EmailAddress"],["email1@domain.com"]);
permissionDE.Rows.Remove(["EmailAddress"],["email2@domain.com"]);
permissionDE.Rows.Remove(["EmailAddress"],["email3@domain.com"]);
permissionDE.Rows.Remove(["EmailAddress"],["email4@domain.com"]);
permissionDE.Rows.Remove(["EmailAddress"],["email5@domain.com"]);
permissionDE.Rows.Remove(["EmailAddress"],["email6@domain.com"]);

</script>
```

Comment: Ways in which this could be improved: 1. create an array of addresses and loop over it calling the remove function for each of them. 2. Better yet store the addresses in a data extension, read the contents and push them into an array and loop over that